# Find range of a function given domain

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find the range of this function given the domain
$D_f=(0,1)$

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4}{1-x}$

I want to solve this without the use of derivatives, any suggestion?
I have tried to solve this by using limits but to no success

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: if you believe that division by 0 is impossible, then you get no defined range because 1/x = 1/0 for x=0, and 4/(1-x)= 4/0 for x=1;

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee but the domain of the function is $(0,1)$ not $[0,1]$.

Comment: sorry for some reason I thought 0 and 1 were the only options for any x, 0<x<1 you get the first one grows as x tends to 0 and the second is smaller as x tend to 0. so the question then becomes, do these cancel out somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the equation
$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4}{1-x}=y$$
you get two solutions
$$x_1= -\frac{\sqrt{y^2-10 y+9}-y+3}{2 y};\;x_2=\frac{\sqrt{y^2-10 y+9}+y-3}{2 y}$$
the minimum value for $y$ is reached when $x_1=x_2$ that is when the square root is zero
$$y^2-10y+9=0$$
which happens for $y_1=1;\;y_2=9$

$y_1=1$ gives $x_1=x_2=-1$ which is outside the domain, while $y_2=9$ gives $x_1=x_2=\frac{1}{3}$

Therefore the minimum has coordinates $\left(\frac{1}{3};\;9\right)$

The range of the function is $[9,+\infty)$

Infinity because $x=0$ and $x=1$ are asymptotes and $y\to \infty$

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=y=\frac{1-x+4x}{x(1-x)}=\frac{3x+1}{x(1-x)}\\y(x-x^2)=3x+1\\yx-yx^2=3x+1\\yx^2+(3-y)x+1=0$$
Now you must have $\Delta\geq 0$ (where $\Delta$ is the discriminant) otherwise $x$ isn't real so $y$ isn't in range and intersect the solution set with the solutions to
$0<x_1<1$ or $0<x_2<1$

Comment: According to the book the answer is 

$ V_f=[9, \infty) $

Maybe I interpret the question wrong?

Comment: @einar The answer is $[9,\infty)$ did you try using my method? It should give you exactly $V_f=[9,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks! I had some problem solving the last step but I get the right answer now :)

Answer (score 1):

Use AM-GM,
let $\dfrac1x=y$, $1< y< \infty$

$f(1/y)=y+\dfrac4{1-1/y}=y+\dfrac{4y}{y-1}=5+y-1+\dfrac4{y-1}\geq5+4=9$